# Using PowerPoint-created figures in LaTeX

Tags: eps, powerpoint

I have created many figures on PowerPoint (my advisor doesn't use LaTeX) and now I would like to export them to LaTeX for my dissertation. I don't want to save the picture as .png because not only the quality is reduced, but also the font would be different.

My current workflow:

1. Save the drawing canvas on PowerPoint as .svg.
2. change the file type to .eps_tex using Inkspace (also tried with .pdf_tex).
3. Use `\import{figurename.eps_tex}` or `\input{figurename.eps_tex}` on my LaTeX file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}


\begin{document}


Figure \ref{fig:fig1} shows an example of figure made in PowerPoint, saved as .png and included in LaTeX.

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Sample_PPT_fig.png}
    \caption{PNG figure}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:fig2} shows an example of figure made in PowerPoint, saved as .svg, imported to Inkscape, and saved as .eps.

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\textwidth} % Scales the figure
    \input{Sample_PPT_fig.eps_tex}
    \caption{EPS\_TEX figure}
    \label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:fig3} shows the EPS configuration used on Inkscape.

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{eps_options.png}
    \caption{EPS export options used on Ikscape}
    \label{fig:fig3}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:fig4} shows an example of figure made in PowerPoint, saved as .pdf and imported into LaTeX.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Sample_PPT_fig.pdf}
    \caption{PDF figure}
    \label{fig:fig4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of output]

However, the text of some of the figures get misconfigured in the process and I have to manually edit the .eps_tex file to put the text in the right place. While this works, I have too many figures to do this for.

I'm hoping there is a simple way to do this - perhaps it's a matter of configuration or there is a better extension?

EDIT: I have included a sample of misconfigured file and how adding the picture with different methods reflects on the document. Ideally I would like to have Figure 2, but with the text in the correct line breaks. This was a very simple sample, but sometimes all the text gets bundled up (like it would be "Text box 1Text box 2This is a red star" in a single line).

*See sample project on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dskrdsjqnqkq*

Comment: Can you save PowerPoint's output as a pdf? Then you could include the figures in LaTeX as you would with a png image.

Comment: I think you used PowerPoint to make scientific or math diagrams, because the functionality it has, just an idea, use Mathcha.io or a LaTeX way (TikZ) generate the diagrams, it is much more pleasant.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy I think the reason is that the "advisor" asks for PowerPoint file, and when there's already a PowerPoint file available it would be a lot of effort to rewrite the content in LaTeX.

Comment: Can you show an example of "misconfigured font"? (by the way you can install Latin Modern font on PowerPoint, which normally results in the same font as default LaTeX.

Comment: @user202729 Yeah.

Comment: Alternatively: even if the advisor don't use LaTeX, can't you just send the compiled PDF instead? PDF should be readable everywhere.

Comment: if you simply print the powerpoint to a pdf file and use pdflatex you don't need svg, inkscape, eps, etc just use `\includegraphics[page=2]{yourfile.pdf}` to include page 2 of the powerpoint as a scalable inclusion into the latex document.